# Pivot data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, transpose

I have a sales data which is in a week-wise format as shown below:

| cw | customers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022_6 | 2190 |
| 2022_7 | 2148 |
| 2022_8 | 2407 |
| 2022_9 | 3280 |
| 2022_10 | 3915 |
| 2022_11 | 1396 |

But I want to transpose my data in the format as below: (I am trying to get through with a for loop)

| calendar_week | t-1 | t-2 | t-3 | t-4 | t-5 | t-6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022_6 | 2190 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2022_7 | 2148 | 2190 |  |  |  |  |
| 2022_8 | 2407 | 2148 | 2190 |  |  |  |
| 2022_9 | 3280 | 2407 | 2148 | 2190 |  |  |
| 2022_10 | 3915 | 3280 | 2407 | 2148 | 2190 |  |
| 2022_11 | 1396 | 3915 | 3280 | 2407 | 2148 | 2190 |

It would be great if anyone could help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the result dataset `t-1`, `t-2` etc... columns are more like the shifts of the `customers` column of the original dataset shift period starting from 0. So you can generate the DataFrame like this:

```
for i in range(6):
  df[f't-{i+1}'] = df['customers'].shift(i)
```